# Drizzle Columns Schema JSON stores my JSON as text in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, typescript, postgresql, orm, drizzle

I'm using Drizzle for a Typescript backend that serves a few API endpoints. My database is Postgresql and there's a JSON column.

```
export const transactions = pgTable("transactions", {
    id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
    my_json: json('my_json')
});
```

I if try to store `{"hello":"world"}` from a supabase table editor, this is what I'm getting:

[image]

If I try to insert my {"hello":"world"} using TS/Drizzle, this is what I'm getting:

[image]

Somehow I can't find a setting or a way to make drizzle store it as a real JSON object and not a string version of it.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug. There is an issue open on the Drizzle ORM Github https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/724

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently (June 2023) it's not possible due to a bug: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/724

You'll need to execute a raw DML query instead:
`` db.execute(sql`INSERT INTO table(foo_id, foo_json)...VALUES(123,${yourObject})`) ``

For example this worked for me.

```
const statement = sql`
        INSERT INTO wikidata_article (wikidata_id, category, grade, en_raw_length, en_url_title, labels, sitelinks)
        VALUES (${articleDetails.wikiDataId}, ${articleDetails.category}, ${articleDetails.grade}, ${articleDetails.enBytes}, ${articleDetails.enUrlTitle}, ${articleDetails.labels}, ${articleDetails.sitelinks})
        ON CONFLICT (wikidata_id) DO UPDATE
        SET 
            category = ${articleDetails.category},
            grade = ${articleDetails.grade},    
            en_raw_length = ${articleDetails.enBytes},
            en_url_title = ${articleDetails.enUrlTitle},
            labels = ${articleDetails.labels},
            sitelinks = ${articleDetails.sitelinks}
        `;
        await db.execute(statement);
```

Answer (score 2):

I add a solution from the issue: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/724#issuecomment-1650670298

Replace with a `::json` whenever you write or update

```
const product = await tx
  .insert(products)
  .values({
    entityId: input.entityId,
    eventType: input.eventType,
    // payload: input.payload, Instead use 
    payload: sql`${input.payload}::json`, // or ::jsonb
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

create a lil sqlJSON helper to solve this...:

```js
import type { SQL } from 'drizzle-orm';
import type { PgColumn } from 'drizzle-orm/pg-core';

export const sqlJSON = <TC extends PgColumn, TD = Exclude<TC['default'], SQL<unknown>>>(column: TC, data: TD) => {
  return sql`${JSON.stringify(data)}::json`;
};


// usage:

const MyTable = pgTable('my_table', {
  jsonData: json('json_data').$type<{ data: string; }>
})

sqlJSON(MyTable.jsonData, { data: 'to make JSON' })
```